# Changes to React Router V4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am having problems with React Router V4. I have the following code

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Route path='/overview/day/:date' component={OverviewDetail}></Route>
      <Route path='/overview/day' component={Overview}></Route>
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

Whenever I go to page `/overview/day` it renders the Overview Component fine. However when I go `overview/day/2015-06-01` it renders both components. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just because your `OverviewDetail` is a descendant of `Overview`?

Comment: add exact prop to the second route `<Route exact path='/overview/day' component={Overview} />` and also use switch if you only want to render a single route based on match

Answer (score 4):

Your example should be like this

```
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

<Provider store={store}>
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/overview/day' component={Overview} />
      <Route path='/overview/day/:date' component={OverviewDetail} />
    </Switch>
  </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on [Rei Dien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963793/changes-to-react-router-v4/42964293#42964293), which I believe to be the correct one, and to also give some more background, the example should indeed be:

```
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

<Provider store={store}>
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/overview/day' component={Overview} />
      <Route path='/overview/day/:date' component={OverviewDetail} />
    </Switch>
  </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

From the [official documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)

> **`<Switch>`**
>
> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the
>   location.
>
> **How is this different than just using a bunch of `<Route>`s?**
>
> `<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In
>   contrast, every `<Route>` that matches the location renders inclusively.
>   Consider this code:
>
> ```
> <Route path="/about" component={About}/> 
> <Route> path="/:user" component={User}/> 
> <Route component={NoMatch}/>
> ```
>
> If the URL is /about, then 
>   `<About>`, `<User>`, and `<NoMatch>` will all render because they all > match the path. This is by design, ...